# Need a detail info about how to learn and start developing Mobile Application

Tags: android, mobile-phones

hey guys, till now i have developed web applications but know i'm thinking to get hands on Mobile Application. So how to i start it n from where coz i have no idea about Android,iPhone,Symbian etc.. nor i dn't have a big Phone to know how applications runs on it..
mainly i want to focus on Android Applications, is there any simulator for Android Phones, i dn't even know how to use simulators..I just need a step-by-step tutorial for mobile app development n Android Application.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "getting started with android development"? I have. Lo and behold, the first result is a step-by-step tutorial: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/getting-started-with-android-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://developer.android.com . This is the official website for Android and it contains a detailed documentation regarding the procedure to download Android SDK...configuring and running programs in Eclipse. Apart from that you do have various other websites that offer you basic documentation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405695/importantuseful-websites-for-the-android-related-stuff